# Microsoft Graph cannot select on expand statement for /groups

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to access all members of all groups through Microsoft Graph. I want to gather this in a single call as opposed to iterating over each group.

I only want to select a subset of information for the expanded members.

I can't find a way to do this, but I believe it is supported. What is the appropriate way to select on an expand?

As far as I can tell, this should work to give me what I want, however, the result returns without the `members` property:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=members($select=id,userPrincipalName)
```

This, however, does return all members, but provides *way* more information than I'm looking for:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=members
```

I've tried this in two places:

1. [Microsoft Graph API explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer/) (Specific examples from above).
2. Within my code in a real environment. I'm going to omit the code here as the results from code are the same as the Graph Explorer.

edit: While I've accepted Marc's answer as it helps solve this here, for others, I'm going to note that the following will still return groups and members in a single (albeit large) response:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=members
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your query is properly formatted from an OData perspective, Groups doesn't implement this pattern. You'll need to query the membership for each Group separately.

What you *can* do is reduce the number of calls using [JSON Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0). You can batch up to 20 calls at a time. The most straightforward way to do this is to set your page size to 20 records like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id&$top=20
```

For each page, you then send a batch request for the groups on that page:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/groups/{group-id}/members"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/groups/{group-id}/members"
    },
    //...
    {
      "id": "20",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/groups/{group-id}/members"
    } 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey Marc, when you mentioned "Groups doesn't implement this pattern", are you talking about the "select" pattern on expand, or the "expand" pattern overall? My initial thought was you were talking about the select on expand

Comment: I was referring to the expand + select pattern (`$expand($select=x,y,z,)`). You can expand `members` but there are some painful limits. I believe it will only return 20 members for example. It also, as you've noticed, returns a _huge_ dataset, _far_ more than you likely need.

Comment: A similar question came up yesterday so you might find this answer helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55246779/105518

Comment: not sure why microsoft didn't just make it so the first page of memberships were available and link you to the next page if it exists. the way it is now is awful because fetching all azure group memberships - you have `O(N)` instead of `O(n/batchsize)`. This is a huge slowdown for big instances.