# Retrieve all Users from all Groups?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to see all of the Groups and all of the Users inside those Groups using Microsoft Graph?  I don't see anything like that in the documentation.

When calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/
```

I get the information about my Groups but I don't see any information about the Users in those Groups.

I have also tried calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{{userID}}/memberOf
```

and I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'memberOf'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "13488c8e-124f-4161-ad2b-1dc03a302dc9",
      "date": "2019-03-18T16:13:23"
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure why or if it's even related.

I granted the Service Principal all of the Microsoft Graph permissions.

Comment: if you're looking for direct members of a group.. you could use `List members api`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0 although, with this api you will need to go one by one for all groups.. Microsoft Graph API also supports `$expand` for some of the API's but I'm not sure if groups would expand to give you all members in a single call.. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/overview/query_parameters#expand

Comment: I quickly tried and a query like this works `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=members` it does expand the members as well.. although there are some limitations documented for $expand operator on Microsoft Docs.. I'll try to collate everything and add an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see 2 possible approaches that you could work with -

1. **Make use of `$expand` operator in the call for groups.**

   `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=members`

   This way you could get information about groups and it's members in a single call. Here's a link to [Microsoft documentation on $expand parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter)

   *Disclaimer*: Microsoft Docs for expand parameter have a note which says something like

   > With Azure AD resources that derive from directoryObject, like user
   >   and group, $expand is only supported for beta and typically returns a
   >   maximum of 20 items for the expanded relationship.

   Although, above mentioned query, which uses v1.0 did work fine for me at least from Graph explorer with a low number of group members. So you may need to test further.
2. **Find members for each group individually**

   In this approach you can use [List Members API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0)

   ```
    GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members
   ```

Permissions required for each API are pretty well described in their respective documentation on Microsoft Docs links.

Comment: I believe the docs are outdated with respect to this only being supported in beta, but my understanding is the ~20 members being returned is accurate. Using `{group}/members` is a more reliable method. It's also a lot easier on bandwidth since you can `$select` only the fields you care about (`$expand=members($select={props})` isn't supported here).

Comment: Those are very good suggestions @MarcLaFleur.. thanks for your inputs.

Comment: This is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542595/microsoft-graph-cannot-select-on-expand-statement-for-groups/54565798?noredirect=1#comment97234046_54565798

Answer (score 2):

Were looking for answers to this 20 limit issue mentioned by @Rohit. That limitation is still there it seems

But if you use the delta api, you'll get all members and the response is even limited to just the id of the users

So use:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$expand=members`

Comment: When I checked Graph Explorer helper page I could not see delta api, Could you explain the issue a little more? Should I update all my graph api call like this to get a trustable result?

Comment: @husnu you can read about the delta api here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview