# Microsoft Graph: Groups request failing with error about expanded list entry types

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Here's the graph call I'm making:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=members
```

This works successfully in two place:

1. [Microsoft Graph API Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer/)
2. Within my (same) code in multiple real environments (about 50 environments working correctly). Results are same as graph explorer

On one individual real environment, I'm getting an HTTP 400 with the following error message provided in the response from Microsoft Graph API (code BadRequest):

> The type 'microsoft.graph.contact' of a resource in an expanded link is not compatible with the element type 'microsoft.graph.directoryObject' of the expanded link. Entries in an expanded link must have entity types that are assignable to the element type of the expanded link.

Can you help me understand what might be causing this? Is this an issue on the remote Graph API side? Is there any way to work around it while still getting this data back in one API call?

PS I'm aware of batching as per this stackoverflow link mentioning that we can't subselect-- [Microsoft Graph cannot select on expand statement for /groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542595/microsoft-graph-cannot-select-on-expand-statement-for-groups) --but I would like to still make this in one call

Comment: This is a head scratcher but there are a couple of things we could try to rule things out: 1) Can you sign in to this tenant with Graph Explorer and execute this query? (i.e. is this a tenant problem vs a code problem), 2) Could you try using the `/beta` version and see if you get any different results?, and 3) Is there anything unique about this tenant (i.e. is this a different license than the other 50 you've tested)?

Comment: Could this be related to a user for this particular tenant and a known limitation regarding type of contacts supported in v1.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#organization-contacts-available-in-only-beta .. since the error message mentions `microsoft.graph.contact` of a resource in expanded link is not compatible.. Hopefully you will be able to find that by testing as proposed by Marc LaFleur in comment above

Comment: > 1) Can you sign in to this tenant with Graph Explorer and execute this query?

This worked from graph explorer for my customer the first time... which is weird because after that I went back and very much confirmed that I was getting the 400 and message from the same request from my code.
Beta endpoint got some message about browser storage limit I think (assuming that's not an issue w/ the endpoint). I haven't been able to test w/ the customer enough to rule either way on beta endpoint.

3) The failing tenant (now I also have a 2nd customer with the issue) both have CSP accounts.

Comment: Marc, Rohit, thanks. I'm gonna plan on rewriting the code to enumerate through groups as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246031/retrieve-all-users-from-all-groups/55246779#55246779 as opposed to trying to grab it from /groups?$expand=members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with a workaround rather than finding a solution to the original issue. I think I was hitting something on the Graph side with regards to what object types are supported by ?$expand.

Workaround:

- Gather list of groups from:

  GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
- Enumerate list of members for each group using this:

  GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members

This is similar to solution #2 here:
[Retrieve all Users from all Groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246031/retrieve-all-users-from-all-groups/55246779#55246779)