# GraphServiceClient expand function

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, expand

I am working with the .NET Microsoft.Graph library in order to sync users and groups. The following query returns all 269 groups:

```
var msGraphGroup =
    await graphServiceClient.Groups
        .Request()
        .Top(999)
        .GetAsync();
```

Since the groups are nested, I need to get also the members:

```
var msGraphGroup_ =
    await graphServiceClient.Groups
        .Request()
        .Top(999)
        .Expand("members")
        .GetAsync();
```

This query returns the groups with the members, but just 100 items. Why not all 269?

I wrote also the following:

```
var msGraphGroup =
    await graphServiceClient.Groups
        .Request()
        .Expand("members")
        .GetAsync();

List<Microsoft.Graph.Group> all = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Group>();

while (msGraphGroup.Count > 0)
{
    all.AddRange(msGraphGroup.CurrentPage);
    if (msGraphGroup.NextPageRequest == null)
    {
        break;
    }
    msGraphGroup = await msGraphGroup.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
}
```

Is there a way to get all groups with all members in one single query?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation on Graph API Throttling Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#pattern), expand operator is quite expensive and that is why it is limited. Also it does not support select so you will end up fetching all user info in the expand.

As of now you have to query the members of each group separately. There is a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542595/microsoft-graph-cannot-select-on-expand-statement-for-groups) to use the batch API to reduce calls.

Note: Your question is similar to [Retrieve all Users from all Groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246031/retrieve-all-users-from-all-groups/55246779#55246779) and [Microsoft Graph cannot select on expand statement for /groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542595/microsoft-graph-cannot-select-on-expand-statement-for-groups). Check them out for more insight.